Ошибки Android Studio при компиляции
Буквально недели 2 назад все запускалось а теперь такие ошибки. В чем может быть проблема?
Could not find com.liaoinstan.springview:library:1.7.0.
Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0.
Could not resolve com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.4.
Could not find org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006.```

